# Can anyone help to fix my discord python bot announce embed command?

Tags: python, command, bots, discord

I have recently been trying to make a bot for my server which would have a command in which you could say `!ann <channel> <message>` and the bot would post an embed in which the message would also be displayed.

I have only been able to get this far, and yet even this does not work.

```
if message.content.upper().startswith("!ANN"):
  if "534116283487223809" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
    args = message.content.split(" ")  
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**9Lounge Announcement**", description="$s" % (" ".join(args[1:])), color=0x0000ff)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Would any of you be able to help?

Regards

H

Comment: ok, first of all, are you using rewrite? if not, I suggest switching to it. Also, use `@bot.command`, not on message.

Comment: @RandomChannel What do you mean by rewrite? I am using repl.it. And how would I convert to @bot.command?

Comment: I mean are you using discord.py rewrite?

Comment: I'm going to make it work for you.

Comment: @harrisson Copp

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got this to work for you. Feel free to change it to your liking.

```
@bot.command(ignore_extra=False)
async def sendd(ctx, channel, *message):
    color = discord.Color.from_rgb(random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
    channel = channel.replace('<#', '')
    channel = int(channel.replace('>', ''))
    channe = bot.get_channel(channel)
    message = (" ".join(message[0:]))
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Sendd", description=f"{message}", color=color)
    await channe.send(embed=embed)
```

of course you have to declare the bot as 'bot' or else it won't work. This worked for me tho.

Comment: I made it sendd plus prefix at the beginning so ?sendd if ? Is the prefix

Comment: You can change the async def thing to the command name you want it to be